# How can i start web-mode at a file's startup?

Tags: init-file, web-mode, config

I want my emacs to start `.php` and others web files in web mode so i copied this code which is on the [web-mode webpage](http://web-mode.org):

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[agj]sp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))
```

But it's not working.
Here's my .emacs config:

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")
         t)
(package-initialize)

(require 'linum)
(require 'linum-relative)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(linum-relative-on)

(require 'auto-complete)
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(require 'yasnippet)
(yas-global-mode 1)

(set-language-environment "UTF-8")

(setq frame-title-format "Emacs")

(menu-bar-mode -1)

(tool-bar-mode -1)

(scroll-bar-mode -1)

(set-default 'cursor-type 'hbar)

(load-theme 'dracula t)


(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[agj]sp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is in error:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

It doesn't open `.tpl` files *and* `.php` files in web-mode, it opens files ending `.tpl.php` in web-mode.

Amusingly, I have that in my init file also; it came from somewhere on the web. And it doesn't work for me either.

So, to fix it, add two separate lines, one for each filetype:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
```

Comment: You can also use `"\\.tpl\\|\\.php\\'"`.

Comment: It's also done wrong on the web-mode homepage: http://web-mode.org/

Comment: @Timm I had emailed the web-mode people, and they say that that behavior is intentional. It seems wrong to me, but I don't manage web-mode.

Answer (score 1):

The lines you copied associate `.phtml` files with web-mode. You need another couple of lines to associate `.php` and `.co` files as well.

Comment: The one after does `.php` and `.tpl` Normally so i don't understand what you want to say by this

Comment: No, it adds files that end in `.tpl.php`, e.g. `red.tpl.php`.